# cx_freeze Python project to app in windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert a python project to application but every time i include my personal package i got this error :

```
sourcePackageDir = os.path.dirname(module.file)
File "c:\python\python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 221, in dirname return split(p)[0]
File "c:\python\python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split p = os.fspath(p)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: Can you show us what is `module.file` equal to ?

Comment: it have a lot of code i don't know how to show all of this here

Comment: Not the code but just the result of `print(module.file)` and `print(type(module.file))` commands.

Comment: the module file is model.hydro and the result of the two printing is :                                               <module 'model.hydro' from 'C:\\freezeSetupfolder\\app-project\\model\\hydro.py'>
and  <class 'module'> for print type

Comment: When i remove pandas and numpy from imports it work fine but if one of them cx_freeze give me this error

Comment: I can't see where it can be coming from maybe sharing a little more on what you have already tried and the results you got may help people answering your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bousof, actually i switched to Pyinstaller and it work fine

Comment: Cool! That was one of the solutions I've seen on internet but there was so much more I don't know if it's possible to list them all. I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I have the same error. I think there's a bug in the new cx_freeze module (6.2). I'm working with python 3.8.1

Comment: It is a bug in cx_freeze. I reverted to my last known working commit (0ce8086) and it works now. You can probably work with a newer commit but I don't have the time now to experiment.